# How to explain Erlang's supervision trees?

Tags: erlang, erlang-otp, erlang-supervisor

I tried to explain supervision trees.

My best try is:

ok, You get a chocolate box from the factory, with warranty, 
"Every bit will taste good."
Then if you find that one bit taste funny. You can throw the whole box
away. Because you get a new from the factory. 
That is like supervision trees in Erlang. If one thread misbehave. There is a risk that all threads have bad state. 
If that is the case, the supervisor throw all threads away and start over. 
Like the chocolate box, you are the supervisor when you throw the box.

Answer (score 10):

You have processes that do things - **worker processes**. There may be many **workers** of a **type** - all the same - but there may also be *many types of workers*.

You build an application by writing types of worker processes and deploying them.

Overseeing the **worker processes** are **supervisor processors** - and overseeing the **supervisor processes** are **supervisor processes** (turtles all the way up, except for the top one who's the daddy!)

All supervisors are the same. They only have 2 jobs:

1. look out for their workers (if they
   start crashing restart them in the
   way that that type of worker needs
   to be restarted)
2. if too many workers crash too often
   report up the line to their
   supervisors (by crashing and letting
   their supervisor restart them in the
   way that they need to be restarted)

That's it. You build small sub-systems out of special types of worker processes that you have designed and compose them into large, multi-server clusters using the *same nearly-bug-free, comprehensively-tested supervisors* as everyone else and some standard workers that operate on the supervision tree to do things like move sub-systems from one machine to another (these standard workers are codified in behaviours like OTP applications and OTP gen_servers and stuff.

Answer (score 2):

In [my article](https://web.archive.org/web/20100507101922/http://mue.tideland.biz/software-architecture-with-erlangotp-part-7-s) I described it this way:

> In some parts Erlang is like the real
>   life: there are many processes which
>   do the real work and some which are
>   supervising them. And there's a
>   hierarchy. As I said, real life.
>   ****smile****

The rest of the article tries to give a deepe insight into the Erlang supervision tree concept.

mue

Answer (score 0):

In response to Mue above, the link has changed. The correct address is now: http://mue.tideland.biz/software-architecture-with-erlangotp-part-7-s